# zoo's NA handling methods in r

Tags: r, zoo, na

I am experimenting with different imputation method in zoo 
So far I tried on my dataset `na.locf, na.approx, na.spline`. However, when I tried the same dataset with `na.StructTS` which uses seasonal Kalman filter it returns me the following error:

> Error in StructTS(y) : 'x' must be numeric

Did I miss something? Any help is appreciated.

**UPD1**
my code:

> empty <-zoo(order.by=seq.Date(head(index(df1.zoo),1),tail(index(df1.zoo),1),by="days"))
>   merged<-na.StructTS(merge(df1.zoo,empty))

here is `df1.zoo`:

```
           1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 
2012-01-01 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  42
2012-01-02 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  57
2012-01-03 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  51 
2012-01-04 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  41 
2012-01-05 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  56 
2012-01-06 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  55
```

here is `empty`:

Comment: Is it possible include a `dput` of the dataset and the specific command you're trying to run?

Comment: `na.StructTS` uses `StructTS` and `StructTS` requires that a complete cycle be 1 which implies that `"Date"` class won't work..  `?na.StructTS` has some examples.